# How to update GridView before ViewSwitcher animation happens?

Tags: android, gridview, viewswitcher

I work on a Battleships game as my first Android application.

I decided to use a ViewSwitcher that holds two GridViews. One **bUserGrid** is for the User field (hosting user ships), **bComputerGrid** is for the Computer field (showing user shots).

```
GridView bComputerGrid, bUserGrid, mComputerGrid, mUserGrid;
ViewSwitcher bigSwitcher, miniSwitcher;
```

User strikes (taps Computer field).The application runs the AsyncTask **userAttack** which defines whether that strike was successful or not.

```
bComputerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    runUserAttack(position);
  }
});
```

If user missed, then in a **onPostExecute()** section of **userAttack** I call **notifyDataSetChanged()** in order to refresh the **bComputerGrid**.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        ...
        bComputerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mComputerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        firstmateMsg.setText(message);
        mUserBundle = mUserAttack.getmUBundle();
        mUserAttack=null;
        if (isCancelled()) return;
        if (mUserBundle.getBoolean("userMissed")) {
            mComputerAttack = new computerAttack();
            mComputerAttack.execute(mComputerBundle);
        } else {
            if (doesWon(seqComputerShips)) {
                showDialog(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn’t happen! Following statement doesn’t update **bComputerGrid**, if user misses.

```
bComputerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then here in **onPostExecute()** section of **userAttack** I start AsyncTask **computerAttack**. In **onPreExecute()** section of **computerAttack** I switch **bComputerGrid** to **bUserGrid** by calling

```
bigSwitcher.showNext();
```

Switching happens but **bComputerGrid** hasn't been updated before that!

Computer does its strike and successfully refreshes the user field in **onProgressUpdate()** section of **computerAttack** by calling **bUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**. When Computer missed, the application comes to wait for the user strike (tap) again.

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... messages) {
        ...
        mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        bUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mComputerBundle = mComputerAttack.getmCBundle();
        mComputerAttack=null;
        if (field_switch) {
            switchViews();
        }

    }
```

But why I can’t refresh **bComputerGrid** before that switching and Computer shot happens?

Could you, please, help me?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't invoke notifyDataSetChanged() before changing the underlying data of the adapter? Set breakpoint at bComputerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, fiction! I set the breakpoint and sure that underlying array changes before I invoke notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Where you update your adapters? You change underlying data of the adapter, or you change the adapter list?
Adapters are also part of the UI, so changes of the adapter itself should happen only in a GUI thread. I got a couple of UI Exceptions (on display) telling me so in some other project as I changed the adapter contents in a Service Thread.
Eventually you have to recreate your adapter list to reflect changes in underlying data?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, Oliver!  I change underlying data of the adapters in onPostExecute() section just before notifyDataSetChanged() call. updateSeqComputerShips(int1D_to_int2D(mUserAttack.getmUBundle().getIntArray("computerShips")));